# Is it Possible to show more than 7 weeks?

Tags: fullcalendar

Using http://fullcalendar.io/

Is it possible to show 7 or more weeks in the full month view?

Anyone have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a customized view. Fullcalendar v2.4.0 demo https://jsfiddle.net/ktLxrw0v/

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next,today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'basicWeek, month, nineWeek'
  },
  views: {
    nineWeek: {
      type: 'basicWeek',
      duration: {
        weeks: 9
      },
      buttonText: 'Nine Week'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Set the type to month but that's what I'm looking for. Thank you!